# AttributeError at /add/4/ 'Item' object has no attribute 'filter'

Tags: python, django, django-views

I'm getting error **AttributeError at /add/4/**   'Item' object has no attribute 'filter'

at

`if order.item.filter(item__id = item.id).exists():`

I'm trying add Items based on the ids in to cart. The item is being added in the cart table but showing above error.

my **views.py**

```
@login_required(login_url='/login/')
def add_to_cart1(request, id):
    item = get_object_or_404(Item, id=id)
    order_item, created = CartItem.objects.get_or_create(
         item=item,
        user=request.user,
    )
    order_qs = CartItem.objects.filter(user=request.user, ordered=False)
    if order_qs.exists():
        order = order_qs[0]
        if order.item:
            if order.item.filter(item__id = item.id).exists():
                order_item.quantity += 1
                order_item.save()
                messages.success(request, "Item qty was updated.")
                return redirect("ItemAddedToCart")
            else:
                order.item.add(order_item)
                messages.success(request, "Item was added to your cart.")
                return redirect("ItemAddedToCart")
    else:
        order = CartItem.objects.create(
            user=request.user,  )
        order.item.add(order_item)
        messages.success(request, "Item was added to your cart.")
    return redirect("ItemAddedToCart")
```

my **models.py**

```
class CartItem(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(AUTH_USER_MODEL, null=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    item    = models.ForeignKey(Item, null=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True ,null=True)
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True ,null=True)
    quantity = models.IntegerField(default=1)
    ordered = models.BooleanField(default=False)
```

Comment: `order.item` is an object, not a `QuerySet`

Answer (score 0):

Your model creates an FK to `Item`, meaning that each `CartItem` instance has a reference to a single item.

It's not clear from your question what the filter is designed to do, but it looks like you're just trying to get the object (`Item`) that this card item is related to.

You might be after a code block that looks a bit like this:

```py
order_qs = CartItem.objects.filter(user=request.user, ordered=False)
for cart_item in order_qs:
    if cart_item.item:
        order_item.quantity += 1
        order_item.save()
        messages.success(request, "Item qty was updated.")
        return redirect("ItemAddedToCart")
```

It's very possible I'm misunderstanding the models here though as I don't know what `order_item` etc are

Comment: First off thank you so much for being so kind and taking the time to help me. I tried you answer but I'm getting below error.

`Manager isn't accessible via Item instances`

Comment: Oh of course, sorry. I think you might just want `object.item` - that is the object the FK points to, and I don't really understand what / why you're trying to filter. I'll edit my answer to reflect this